# How to interpret numerical values for a NN regression problem

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, cross-validation, interpretation, scales

I'm working a Neural Network for a supervised regression problem. I have to predict the final grade for a student, given a set of attributes from a survey. I have a set of 455 entries and 33 features. Many of them are nominal, so I converted them using the 1-to-n mapping.

So I scaled every value (Y too) in range 0 to 1 using the upper and lower bound given.

So I thought about this. There are many values that represents something that in real-life scenarios would be negative in order to a student to get an high grade. Does it make sense to invert the numerical value of such attributes? If a student has a lot of freetime, equal to 5, in a range of 1-to-5, converting it to 1 and then scale it in 0-to-1 has a different impact on the result? Negative things should be values with lower numerical values in respect of positive things?

Thank you very much! I hope I explained my problem well enough.

P.S.:
Using a cross-validation method, a logistic activation function in a mean squared error plus a regularization term with a gamma of 0.00001, I get an error on the training set equal to 0.0019 and on the validation equal to 0.043 with 3 neurons.